# Azure Search - Error

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

When trying to index documents we are getting this error:

```
{"Token PropertyName in state ArrayStart would result in an invalid JSON object. Path 'value[0]'."}
```

Our code for indexing using the .NET library is :

```
using (var indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchServiceName, indexName, new SearchCredentials(apiKey)))
  {
      indexClient.Documents.Index(IndexBatch.Create(IndexAction.Create(documents.Select(doc => IndexAction.Create(doc)))));
  }
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: Can you provide the Class description of the object you are trying to index?

Comment: Thanks for your time. The class is a simple POCO: public class Address
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Addr { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int Flag { get; set; }
    }

Comment: can you provide sample document which you are trying to Index?

Comment: The error message looks like it might be a bug in the SDK. Can you provide your index definition and some sample documents?

Comment: Hi, as far as the Index definition is concerned, we used the REST API as the .NET library does not allow custom analyzers. I cannot post the definition within comments as it is a little long. I can email it to you. It is a bog standard definition but using a keyowrd analyzer and lowercase tokenfilter. A sample document would look like **{ Id="RHVibGlu", "Addr": "Dublin", "Country": "IE", Flag=2}**

Comment: Thanks. Please email me at Bruce dot Johnston at the usual domain. I'll take a look next week when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Following Bruce's comment, are you using the latest (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search/) Nuget package for Azure Search?

Comment: @bruce - Sorry but I don't have your email address. Where can I get it from?

Comment: I'm avoiding spelling it out so spam bots don't get it. It's my first name, followed by a dot, then my surname, then @microsoft.com

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to repro the issue. An explanation is coming shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of an extra call to `IndexAction.Create`. If you change your indexing code to this, it will work:

```
indexClient.Documents.Index(IndexBatch.Create(documents.Select(doc => IndexAction.Create(doc))));
```

The compiler didn't catch this because `IndexBatch.Create` has a params argument that can take any number of `IndexAction<T>` for any type T. In this case, T was a collection, which is not supported (documents must be objects, not collections).

The programming model for creating batches and actions is changing substantially in the 1.0.0-preview release of the SDK. It will be more type-safe so that mistakes like this are more likely to be caught at compile-time.

Comment: Thank you very much for all this. I will try it.